# Oracle Applications - How to get the value of zd_edition_name

Tags: oracle, oracle-apps

In Oracle Applications 12c release 1 there is a new column that forms part of many primary keys called `zd_edition_name`. This relates to editions that you can have for keeping the database up during changes. So you would have two editions, you can make changes to the non-live on and then just live swap over when you are done (my limited understanding - I am not a dba).

My questions is how can I get the value of `zd_edition_name,` since this is now part of the primary key and also because tables like `fnd_descr_flex_col_usage_tl` would bring back two rows instead of one if you don't pass the value of `zd_edition_name`.

Also what does the zd stand for?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**EBS and Edition Base Redefinition and Online Patching**

The column, zd_edition_name, is just a component of the edition based redefinition feature of an Oracle 11G 2 (or greater) database as you have indicated.

Oracle Applications does not leverage this edition based redefinition database feature until 12.2 EBS.

**The apps owned synonym will display the run time value, SET1 or SET2. It will be one value. For EBS 12.1, I would expect the run time value to be SET1.**

```
APPS@db>    select
  2      zd_edition_name
  3      from
  4      fnd_descr_flex_col_usage_tl
  5      group by   zd_edition_name;
ZD_EDITION_NAME
SET1
```

With the editionable view and the table, we do not have that restriction:

```
APPS@db>SELECT
  2      zd_edition_name
  3  FROM
  4      applsys.fnd_descr_flex_col_usage_tl
  5  GROUP BY
  6      zd_edition_name;
ZD_EDITION_NAME
SET2
SET1
```

In EBS 12.2, one could identify the active file system which should have a correspondence with SET1/SET2 through logging in to the Oracle Apps server(s) and echoing the environment variables:

```
$FILE_EDITION = patch

$RUN_BASE = /u01/R122_EBS/fs1

$PATCH_BASE = /u01/R122_EBS/fs2
```

**By querying the apps owned synonym, this is unnecessary to know the value of ZD_EDITION_NAME (it is a value associated with the run edition which will be the value).**

---

You can view the editionable objects associated with table with a query like this:

```
APPS@db>VAR b_object_name varchar2(30);
APPS@db>EXEC :b_object_name:= 'FND_DESCR_FLEX_COL_USAGE_TL';

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

APPS@db>SELECT
  2      ao.owner,
  3      ao.object_name,
  4      ao.object_type
  5  FROM
  6      all_objects ao
  7  WHERE
  8      1 = 1
  9      AND   owner IN (
 10          'APPS',
 11          'APPLSYS'
 12      )
 13      AND   ao.object_name IN (
 14          :b_object_name,
 15          substr(:b_object_name,1,29)
 16          || '#'
 17      );
OWNER     OBJECT_NAME                    OBJECT_TYPE   
APPLSYS   FND_DESCR_FLEX_COL_USAGE_TL    TABLE         
APPLSYS   FND_DESCR_FLEX_COL_USAGE_TL#   VIEW          
APPS      FND_DESCR_FLEX_COL_USAGE_TL    SYNONYM
```

---

Here are list of versions existing in an EBS instance:

```
APPS@db>SELECT
  2      level,
  3      de.edition_name,
  4      de.parent_edition_name
  5  FROM
  6      dba_editions de
  7  START WITH
  8      de.edition_name = 'ORA$BASE'
  9  CONNECT BY
 10      PRIOR de.edition_name = de.parent_edition_name
 11  ORDER BY
 12      de.edition_name;
  LEVEL EDITION_NAME      PARENT_EDITION_NAME
      1 ORA$BASE
      2 V_20160703_2120   ORA$BASE
      3 V_20160708_1723   V_20160703_2120
    ...
     29 V_20180117_1118   V_20171206_1115
     30 V_20180130_0107   V_20180117_1118
```

For an 12.1 EBS environment, I would expect the starting edition, ORA$BASE, to be the only edition.